# Flutter Attaching a pdf file in Mailer package

Tags: flutter, dart, email, flutter-layout

Hey I'm trying to create a program that asks the user for their email and then send them a pdf file. The program is working but the only problem is that I can't attach the pdf file.

I tried every possible way but it's not working

this is the main code:

```
import'EmailPdf.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     home: HomePage(

     ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the home page

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mailer/mailer.dart';
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server.dart';
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  String _UserEmailForSys;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          TextField(

            onChanged: (String UserEmail){
              _UserEmailForSys = UserEmail;
            },

          ),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
          FlatButton(

            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                SendEmail(_UserEmailForSys);

              });

            },
            child: Text(
              "Flat Button",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          )

        ],
      )


    );
  }
}






SendEmail(String recipients_email) async {

  final recipientsEmail = recipients_email;
String username = '*****';
String password = '******';

 final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
// Use the SmtpServer class to configure an SMTP server:
// final smtpServer = SmtpServer('smtp.domain.com');
// See the named arguments of SmtpServer for further configuration
// options.

// Create our message.
final message = Message()
  ..from = Address(username)
  ..recipients.add('$recipients_email')
  //..ccRecipients.addAll(['destCc1@example.com', 'destCc2@example.com'])
 // ..bccRecipients.add(Address('bccAddress@example.com'))
  ..subject = 'Test Dart Mailer library ::  :: ${DateTime.now()}'
  ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.';
      //..html = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Title of the document</title></head> <body> <h1>PDF Example</h1> <p>Open a PDF file <a href=""/Users/OMAR/Downloads/Terms_of_Use.pdf"">example</a>.</p></body></html>";
  //..html = "<h1>Test</h1>\n<p>Hey! Here's some HTML content</p>";
   //..attachments.add(FileAttachment(file:  File('Assets/Terms.pdf')));

try {
final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
} on MailerException catch (e) {
print('Message not sent.');
for (var p in e.problems) {
print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
}
}




}
```

If someone know how can I exactly use ..Attachment or any other way I will really really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add your pdf path to your mail function

Comment: Can you explain more? I'm trying to attach the pdf from a folder in my laptop not using a URL link.